# How to fix "used struct type value where scalar is required"?

Tags: c, if-statement, return-value

I keep getting this error when I compile and I cannot figure out why. The code block is:

```
static int
run(int nm, int nf)
{
    int i, j;
    int err, n = nm + nf;
    pthread_t thread[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        err = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL,
                  i < nm ? male : female, &shared_bathroom);
        if (err) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: unable to create thread %d: %d\n",
                    progname, __func__, i, err);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (thread[j]) (void) pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error comes up for the line with the if statement under the second for loop. Specifically, I think it is referring to `(thread[j])`.

Comment: You need a scalar type in an `if` condition (arithmetic type, pointer), but `pthread_t` is a struct type (in your implementation at least), not a scalar type. What did you intend with the `if (thread[j])` anyway?

Comment: If any of your threads fail to create you're aborting the program anyway. I'm fairly confident you don't need the if-clause in your join-loop in the first place.

Comment: This is unrelated, but can someone explain to me how `pthread_t thread[n];`, which looks like dynamic array allocation, is working? Shouldn't that cause a compiler error? (In which I feel like a newbie again...)

Comment: @acheong87 It's a variable length array. They were added in C99 and were around as an extension in GCC before that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `thread[j]` returns an instance of the struct `pthread_t`, which you can't use in a boolean context (e.g. in the context of an `if` statement).  There's no reason you need that `if` statement anyway.  Just say:

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use that value in if condition. You can do two things
either you can use like this 
if (thread[j] != NULL_PTR) or you can use check for explicit variable inside structure to check the value.